# IE does not recognise a JSON string when passed in a formData object

Tags: javascript, c#, json, internet-explorer, httppostedfilebase

What i want to do is upload a file via AJAX that has JSON encoded string as its file name. The code i have written works well in Chrome but not so in IE.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
var file = {
            name: "example.jpg",
            guid: "example123",
            index: "0"
        }
var file_obj_string = JSON.stringify(file);
var formData = new FormData();

//curr_ob[0].files[0] is my file upload control
formData.append("FileUpload", curr_ob[0].files[0], file_obj_string);

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/AddFile',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
              //do something
            },

        });
```

Then on the server side:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddFile()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
            //do something with file
            //...
        }
    }
```

On the server side, when running with Chrome, the uploaded FileName comes through correctly as:

"{%22name%22:%22example.jpg%22,%22guid%22:%22example123%22,%22index%22:0}

but if i run it in IE, the fileName attribute as this
"{"

So my question is, why is there a difference to begin with, and what can i do to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: what version of IE? Do you have this meta tag in your index: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> ?

Comment: @floor im using IE 11 and my meta tag is this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`